# Who created New Caprica City in V-world?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, caprica

New Caprica City was one of the cooler aspects of the Caprica show.  New Cap City was like a more detailed grand theft auto game except you could only die once.  When New Caprica was introduced the characters explain that the creator of New Caprica City is mysteriously unknown.

Who created New Caprica City?

Is it ever explained, was it going to be addressed in later episodes?

Comment: It's called [New Cap City](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/New_Cap_City).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Places such as New Cap City and the den-of-sin V-Club aren't supposed to exist. They are the result of people hacking the holoband to create realms outside of the legitimate areas of the V-World. The band's inventor, Daniel Graystone, and his corporation are only beginning to realize how miserably they have failed to control the content of the V-World when the series begins."  [[1](http://thedigitalage.pbworks.com/w/page/24042067/Digital-Media-of-Caprica)]

It appears it is simply unknown who created New Cap City. More likely even would be that a group of hackers made New Cap City, but there's no mention anywhere about whom.